# Typed wrong E-mail address in "To" field. Will CC still be sent?

Tags: email, webmail, yahoo-mail

I'm asking this regarding Yahoo Mail.

Recently I had to send an Email to abc@xyz.com and a carbon copy to def@xyz.com. Unfortunately, I typed the wrong address in the "To" field. So instead of "abc@xyz.com" I typed "ac@xyz.com". A few seconds later I received an E-mail from MAILER-DAEMON@yahoo.com in which it says that the recipient address "ac@xyz.com" was rejected (the address does in fact not exist).

**My question is:**

Has def@xyz.com (this E-mail address does exist) received his/her carbon copy?

Answer (score 3):

Both variants are possible.

Sadly this entirely depends on the SMTP client (your email provider and the technology they use). It might attempt to deliver the message to both accounts separately or together. In the second case it might abort after the failure in SMTP `RCPT TO:` command or it may ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

The usual behavior of a SMTP server is to send the message to the recipients with a correct address if no other reasons inhibit it. Please examine the response of the SMTP session and you will see if the server has accepted the message for delivery to some recipients. You have probably a mail log on you system. If not, I suggest to think about installing one.